# Black cubes appearing using multiple VDBs

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

[image]

Hi wonderful Blender folks,
I've imported multiple VDB files to create smoke in this scene, and in Evee it renders fine, in solid it looks normal, but in Cycles these weird black cubes appear, and in the background. If I only use one or two this happens slightly less. [image]

I've tried turning down the VDB clipping under 'render', making the detail 'fine', using CPU only, open shading language, increasing volume bounces under 'light paths' but still no luck.
Any help would be fantastic, as I need to hand in some shots today.
Thanks!